# Python: Using a Variable Between Functions

Tags: python, function, variables, python-2.7

There's something that's been bugging me (ha!) in Python (I use 2.7). It's that I get `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined` when I run this code:

```
def function1():
    x = 1
    return 0

def function2():
    function1()
    print(x)
    return 0

function2()
```

It's not a serious problem for me, but I am genuinely curious about why this doesn't print 1. It makes sense and flows right in my mind. The function that defines the variable `x` is defined before it is called, and the function is called before `print(x)`. I seriously am not seeing why this code doesn't work. Maybe the way I am thinking about this is flawed. Either way, why doesn't that code print 1? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Lexical scoping: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping

Comment: I changed the title because I realized a bit too late that it was pretty misleading. Sorry! And thanks for all of the great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your thinking is flawed.  The variable `x` defined in `function1` is local to that function.  It doesn't exist anywhere else.  When you call one function with another, that doesn't mean that all the variables from the called function get dumped into the calling function.  Only the return value is passed back.  If you want to use `x` in the second function, you should return it from `function1`.  (Even then, it won't create a variable called `x` in `function2`.  It will only return the *value*, which you can then assign to a variable in `function2` if you want, or print it, or whatever.)

Comment: Maybe you should add that you'd have to print function1() inside of function2().

Comment: I honestly didn't know much about variable scopes before asking this question. I thought they could be used by all parts of the program, even if they were defined inside a function. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The layered approach to Python name spaces is super-critical to being able to write good code, and trust it once you've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

in both functions use `global x` as the 1st line. this will make your code work. but, anyway, passing variables between functions is not a good practice. returning values and using parameters is a good practice.

if you are testing variable-sharing, you're using global variables. for that, unlike javascript, you NEED to use `global x` before trying to get it, as is in php (except that you don't get error in php unless using strict mode).

Comment: It's true that this could fix the problem, however global variables are generally bad to use and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

`x` scope is only *inside* `function1()` that's why you can't print `x` inside `function2()`, even if you're calling `function1()` (when you return from that `function1()`, `x` **will be destroyed**)

Answer (score 0):

Because inside `function1` scope variable `x` is local and `function2` doesn't "see" this variable.